# Pig - expression is not a project expression: (Name: ScalarExpression) Type: null Uid: null)

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, apache-pig

Here is my file data :

```
86246,205,7,707,1078778070,12564,3/2/2012,12,OZ,1,7.59
86246,205,63,6319,107654575,17876,3/2/2012,64,OZ,1,1.59
86246,205,97,9753,1022027929,0,3/2/2012,1,CT,1,5.99
86246,205,25,2509,107996777,31373,3/2/2012,16,OZ,1,1.99
86246,205,55,5555,107684070,32094,3/2/2012,16,OZ,2,10.38
12277270,95,11,1114,107027272,5613,5/25/2013,32,OZ,1,5.49
12277270,95,26,2622,102570020,20361,5/25/2013,30,CT,1,4.79
12277270,95,9,902,104400040,19783,5/25/2013,8.5,OZ,1,1.88
12277270,95,27,2704,103270030,7966,5/25/2013,25,CT,1,13.99
12277270,95,97,9753,10000,0,5/25/2013,1,CT,1,6.7
```

Following step I performed to get my data :

**Step 1:**

```
transaction = LOAD 'projectDemo2/part-m-00000' USING PigStorage(',') as(id:chararray,chain:chararray,dept:chararray,category:chararray,company:chararray,brand:chararray,date:chararray,productsize:float, productmeasure:chararray, purchasequantity:int,purchaseamount:float);
```

**Step-2**

```
chainGroupCust = GROUP transactions BY (chain,id);
```

**Step-3**

```
chainGroupCustSpedings1 = FOREACH chainGroupCust GENERATE group, SUM(transactions.purchaseamount)
as spendings;
```

**Step-4**

```
chainGroupCustSpendings2= FOREACH chainGroupCustSpedings1 generate group.chain as chain,group.id as 
id, spendings;
```

**step-5**

```
chainGroupCustSpendings3= GROUP chainGroupCustSpendings2 BY chain;
```

**Step-6**

```
chainTop10Cust = FOREACH chainGroupCustSpendings3{
chainGroupCustSpedingsSort = ORDER chainGroupCustSpendings2 BY spendings DESC;
top10Cust = LIMIT chainGroupCustSpedingsSort 10;
GENERATE top10Cust;
}
```

While doing **step-6** I am getting the **following error**:

**expression is not a project expression: (Name: ScalarExpression) Type: null Uid: null)**

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Anyone Please help me

Comment: Which version of pig are you using?  At least on trunk, your code works.  (except "transaction" in step 1 should be  "transactions".  But that's probably a typo when copy&pasting)